# How does Nvidia Nemo-toolkit ASR models calculate number of batches?

Tags: pytorch, speech-recognition, nvidia, voice-recognition, pytorch-lightning

I am currently using nemo-toolkit vad, marblenet config. I realised that their training number of batches neither follow what they stated in megtron where global batch = micro_batch * num_par * grad_accum.

For a 1000 train size with batch 128, num_par = 1, grad_acum =1, the num of train is 10.
It doesn't follow the conventional calc. either where num_batch = 1000 // 128 + 1

link to their tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/github/NVIDIA/NeMo/blob/stable/tutorials/asr/Voice_Activity_Detection.ipynb

link to the documentation of their tutorial: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/nemo/user-guide/docs/en/stable/starthere/tutorials.html

anyone able to help out? much thanks

I have tried using other dataset but the calc never adds up.